# Twilio for incoming call At a given point in python code how can I get the current call SID

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I am using Python Flask with ngrok and setting the webhook address to the ngrok url.
Upon incoming call arrival to the webhook address, I need to get the current call SID:

```
@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice()
resp = VoiceResponse()
```

How can I get the current call SID?  (Given account SID and token.) 
I know it can be found in dashboard, but how can I do it in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you wish to get the current call SID for an inbound/incoming call with Flask and ngrok, you could use `request.form['CallSid']` as shown below with `request` in Flask.

```
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    # Read a message aloud to the caller
    resp.say("hello world!", voice='alice') #example, I added this line and it's unneeded
    call_sid = request.form['CallSid']
    print(call_sid)
    return str(resp)
```

If you do an outbound call from the Twilio Client, you could get the current call SID with this:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
client = Client(YOUR-TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR-TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)

call = client.calls.create(
    to= 'NUMBER-TO-CALL',
    from_ = 'YOUR-TWILIO-NUMBER',
    url = 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3'
)
print(call.sid)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have not been able to verify this until tomorrow but wondering I noticed for incoming call you have resp.Say then call-Sid = request.form[“CallSid”].  Do I have to have req.Say before getting the call-Sid?

Comment: you do not need to have the `Say` verb! That is unneeded.